# How to scroll down a edit control to show contents?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mfc, editcontrol

I have a edit control to show the results.But the results are too many so they can't be displayed unless you scroll down it.But how can I achieve it ?[image]

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but use the `SetSel` function to set the cursor at the end of your edit control.

Comment: I want to set my cursor at the bottom of the edit control then put down "WASD" on the keyboard and I can see the contents hidden for the limited length of the edit control.Sorry my English is poor,can you understand me ?

Comment: No sorry, I don't really understand what you want. Maybe you should ask someone to translate.

Comment: Sorry my English is poor, I fixed my problem by modifying the attribute "vertical scroll" of the edit control to "true".I will work harder on my English.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend to use a CScrollView if you want to control scrolling via WASD keys.